# Return Foreign key object in every row

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have two models :

```
public class User{
    @Column(name="user_id)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
}


public class Result{
    private Long id;
    private String score;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private User user;
}
```

So one User can have many results..
Now when I create an endpoint, that returns findAll() for results, I get JSON Result, like this :

```
[
 {"Id":1,"user":{"id":1,"name":"Daniel","lastName":"Dan"},"score":"4"},
 {"Id":2,"user":1,"score":"3",},
 {"Id":3, "user":{"id:2", "name":"Laura","lastName":"Lau"},"score":"3"}
]
```

What I'm seeing is, that when it's the same User Object twice, it doesn't give me the name and lastName of the User.
Only when the name and lastName( the user) changes, then I get the name.
How do I do it so that I get the User info always ?
I can't make it a List, because In other methods I access elements like 
client.getName or client.getId and I can't do that if i have a list and not the object.

Thank you and I apologize if my question is not clearly defined

```
@RequestMapping(value="getAllResults",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Result> getResults(){
    return resultService.findAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your REST endpoint?

Comment: I edited the post and added. resultService just has findAll method from the Repository.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a List or Set of Results in the User class so that each User should be able to reference its different results. You should also annotate the List with @OneToMany. The code should look like this

```
public class User{
    @Column(name="user_id)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascadeType = "CascadeType.ALL")
    private List<Result> results;
}


public class Result{
    private Long id;
    private String score;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private User user;
}
```